# How to make Roundcube work with Postfix + Courier (not dovecot)

Tags: ssl, imap, roundcube

I have a mail server working ok with Postfix+Courirer+MySql (virtual users), and SquirrelMail, I could never configure SqMail properly for message characters sets, so I would like to give a try to Roundcube, I have installed it, I did some configs, but at login screen I always get:

IMAP Error in /usr/share/roundcube/program/lib/Roundcube/rcube_imap.php (196): Login failed for user@domain.tls from AA.BBB.CC.DDD. Could not connect to ssl://domail.tls:993: Conection refused

I've been searching around and testing changes on config but no success, can anybody advice me on how to proceed to achieve the functioning of Roundcube.

My current system still works...

What info is suitable for you to have an idea of what could be wrong?

Comment: You should post this question on serverfault;  StackOverflow is for questions about programming.

Comment: I did it, but there was no answer at all, that's why I tried here....

Comment: Unfortunately, you're even less likely to get an answer here since it's off-topic :(